# How to use codec type properly in NPM

Tags: ffmpeg, fluent-ffmpeg

Trying to use '-acodec libopus' in my npm project as I use in the command line like in the following format;

```
ffmpeg -acodec libopus -i 1.webm 1.wav
```

This works perfectly!  But I would like to make it possible in my NPM project.

How can I set the parameters?
This is what I have , but not working. The output file is broken in a way that some of the frames of the audio file are missing.  It is like there is sound and then there is not. And vice versa.

```
var proc = new ffmpeg({
        source: file,
        nolog: false       
    });


format = "opus"; // or could be wav as well!   


    proc.addOptions([
        '-f ' + format,          
        '-acodec libopus',
        '-vn'
    ]);
```

The purpose is to take audio file from the video file seamlessly.

Without the codec libopus, I get the following errors in the command prompt, so I assume I should handle the same issue in my NPM project as well.

```
[opus @ 00000000006d4520] LBRR frames is not implemented. Update your FFmpeg version to the newest one from Git. If the problem still occurs, it means that your file has a feature which has not been implemented.


[opus @ 00000000006d4520] Error decoding a SILK frame.

[opus @ 00000000006d4520] Error decoding an Opus frame.
```

My library is up to date, I just need to use the codec libopus properly.
Any suggestions?

```
 \node-js>ffmpeg -version
 ffmpeg version N-86175-g64ea4d1 Copyright (c) 2000-2017 the FFmpeg 
 developers
 built with gcc 6.3.0 (GCC)

Output in command line;
xtranscribe transcodeWatson: file : ./data/that/2.webm
progress 62.625273103421605%
progress 100.01224534515762%
SAVED - transcodeWatson : .mp3
out of transcode!
fileSizeInBytes  : 16284033
```

Comment: "but not working" … what happens? What is the generated command-line? Why is your code specifying some format and `-vn`, while the example line you give in the beginning doesn't have that? Note: In ffmpeg it's important where an option is placed, i.e., whether it's an input or an output option. What is your version of ffmpeg? (Show the output of your `ffmpeg` command when run on command-line.)

Comment: @slhck,  updated the question accordingly. 
-vn is used for "no video".

Comment: Similar to the suggestion I made in [your other question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44890636/691711), you need to figure out how to tell fluent-ffmpeg that you want it to decode audio with libopus.  I'm just not sure how to do that with the API fluent defines.  Regular ffmpeg understands it through argument/option order since you say `-acodec libopus` **before** you define you input (or at least that's how I have understood it).

Comment: What confused me is: You show a command in the first line. Then, in your code, you add some unrelated options regarding the format and `-vn`. If you want to show an example, you should make sure that they show the same thing. When I ask “What is the generated command-line?” I wanted to see what fluent-ffmpeg actually runs as a process and what that outputs, i.e. the full, uncut command-line output, as if you were running it in a shell. I'm not sure how to do that with fluent-ffmpeg, but when asking questions on Stack Overflow about ffmpeg, please try to always include that.

Comment: @slhck I think that may be my fault.  In his related question, I was providing raw ffmpeg commands since I am unfamiliar with fluent-ffmpeg.  To achieve the `-vn` (no video) command, the poster should use the API's: [`noVideo()`](https://github.com/fluent-ffmpeg/node-fluent-ffmpeg#novideo-disable-video-altogether) method.

Comment: @zero298 I see, thanks for the info. Good suggestion, yeah. (I never understood why you'd need such libraries in the first place because they just add complexity to an already complex tool.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [the `README`](https://github.com/fluent-ffmpeg/node-fluent-ffmpeg), you can add input options to the process:

```
proc.addInputOption('-acodec libopus');
```

It matters where you place an option in ffmpeg. If you put it before `-i`, it applies to that particular input. If you put it before an output file name, it applies to that output.

Comment: Awesome!  Just like you said it is pretty vital to know what you are doing with those commands. Each parameter has a location . And for input file, that was the way how you set the codec!   Works like a charm . 
Now I need to figure out how to reduce the size of the output audio file seamlessly ! :))  
I created another topic for that! 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44891840/fluent-ffmpeg-how-to-reduce-the-size-of-the-output-file-without-losing-any-sound